# Channels for users to communicate with moderators regarding deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, moderation

There should be a way for a question asker and moderator to have some kind of dialogue after the question has been locked or deleted. Should there not be a way for me to shadow edit for the moderator to review once again and then maybe approve for undelete?

I [asked a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100857/difference-between-island-and-brave-new-world?noredirect=1) which got locked down because it contained content that was not fit for a family audience (which I find a stretch, but fair enough, I am not a moderator). I'm still very interested in asking this question, but I have no possibility to edit what was inappropriate since the moderator just locked it down without giving me the opportunity to change what was unfit. I have no reputation so I can't make any meta questions for the SE in particular (Sci-Fi & Fantasy).

The question had not been up for 30 minutes. Is it not harsh to lock it down with nothing more than a vague explanation and no examples of the unfit content?

I find this really toxic. I've made bad questions on GameDev before, and when I did that Byte56 edited it for me, explained what was wrong and then allowed the question to remain.

So again, should there not be a way for a user to communicate with the moderator after the question has been locked?

Be warned, it was a bad question (I mean I think it was a really kickass question but people don't seem to agree). The beef I had was me not being able to change the question in a way that SE did not find more acceptable.

Comment: Since most of the users here won't have 10k rep on SF&F, would you mind including the content of the [disputed question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100857/difference-between-island-and-brave-new-world) here? It may allow people other than the moderator(s?) involved to chime in.

Comment: Yes, sorry, but I must warn you that it is apparently a question people find a rant. So maybe it was a bad question but I want to be given an opportunity to change the question to something people find a bit more acceptable.

Comment: It's deleted now - next time don't post swear words out in the open, including some really really vulgar words. If you can't resist it - simply don't post.

Comment: @Apeforce Please read [Be nice](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - "Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them ... Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive.".

Answer (score 19):

Your question was not locked, it was deleted.

Normally, questions that are found unsuitable for the site are not locked or deleted, they are [closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) (also called “put on hold”). Closed questions cannot be answered, but other than that they behave normally: they're visible to everyone, they can be edited, they can be commented on. Closed questions can be reopened (by votes from the same people who can vote to close); that usually happens if the question has been edited to fit the site.

Your question was deleted because this was not a normal case. The moderator who deleted it did explain why:

> This question contains content that is inappropriate for a family audience. –  Richard♦

The unfit content is obvious. You posted it.

[image: screenshot]

We try to avoid words that would get the site rejected by automatic content filters. In any case, this paragraph clearly shows that you aren't interested in serious consideration, so we aren't going to go out of our way to make your life easier.

> I find this really toxic

So don't post toxic content.

If you have a genuine question, you can edit your existing post to turn it into a decent question, then [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) it to bring it to a moderator's attention. Moderators can undelete questions.

Comment: How is this an answer to this question?

Comment: How is this not an answer, @Apeforce? It explains why your question was bad, why it was removed, and what you can do to bring it back.

Comment: @gilles - This was precisely my thought process.

Comment: @Apeforce *"the question is if there should not be a way for a user to communicate with the moderator after the question has been locked?"* - And the answer given is *"it wasn't locked, but deleted, for those and those reasons and there already is a perfectly functioning way to communicate with the moderators and improve your question"* - If that isn't a perfectly to the point answer, you're not looking closely enough.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, once a user gets a relatively trivial 20 reputation, they can go to either chat or the specific site's meta (meta is after only *5* reputation) to discuss the question with the community and/or mods.

If you don't have 20 reputation, and for some reason not willing to put a bit of effort to get it, you can always *flag* the question for moderator attention, asking to discuss it and explaining you don't have the rep. A moderator will likely set up a chatroom with write access for you to voice your thoughts.

Other than that, posting it here on meta.stackexchange is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yeah alright so what you're saying is that there is already channels for moderators/posters to talk to each other after the question has been locked? But you have to flag the question? I don't find that very intuitive, when I see a flag I think of flaging as in warning the site moderators of toxic content like racism and insults to other uses

Comment: Flags are also used for that, but they are also "I need a moderator's assistance here please" kind of thing, which seems to fit your usecase.

Comment: @Apeforce Please read [Be nice](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - "Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them ... Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive.".

Comment: Don't flags require 15 rep? In that case, you wouldn't be able to flag unless you could also talk on meta.

Answer (score 3):

You should contact the moderator in the [general site chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) and talk with him/her about this issue and how you would like to handle it in a respectful and polite way.

Comment: Yeah, I tried. But really, I think the comment field is supposed to be used for that, the moderator should say: We don't like this and that, change it or we lock the question

Comment: Chat requires 20 rep, so not relevant for new users.

Comment: @ShadowWizard while that is true it is only required to have this rep on one of the SE sites to be able to talk in other chats too

Comment: Yep, except Stack Overflow and MSE that got their own chat domains.

Comment: This individual raised the issue in chat. I provided him with some more feedback, as did a variety of other site users.